# Symfony's createNotFoundException not returning 404 page

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404

I have a Symfony action where I am trying to return a 404 error when a query returns NULL.

I always get the regular page's template returned and a 200 HTTP return code.

I have checked and my error logs show that the createNotFoundException is firing.

I am running Symfony 2.7.1

Any ideas why this code is not returning the 404 page?

```
<?php

namespace Example\GroupBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Example\GroupBundle\Entity\Group;

/**
 * Class SupportGroupLandingController
 * @package Example\GroupBundle\Controller
 *
 * @Route("/group")
 */
class SupportGroupController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{name}", name="support_group_page")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template("ExampleGroupBundle::group_page.html.twig")
     *
     * @param $name
     * @return array
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ExampleGroupBundle:Group');
        $group = $repo->findOneBy(array('name' => $name));

        if ($group === NULL) {
            error_log('group is null');

            return $this->createNotFoundException('Support Group does not exist');

            error_log('this should not be here');

        } else {
            error_log('group is not null: '.var_export($group, TRUE));
        }

        return array('group' => $group);
    }


}
```

[image: Symfony debug toolbar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not to return `$this->createNotFoundException('Support Group does not exist');` but throw it:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Support Group does not exist');
```

Comment: Thanks! Something so simple :-)